# Fechas Anterior Siguiente con PHP y Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

me pueden ayudar con el siguiente codigo ? Intento que me devuelva por Ajax la fecha anterior o siguiente. 
El problema es que me devuelve la fecha segun el input, pero no se actualiza para seguir navegando entre las fechas.

index.php

```
<?php
    $fecha = date('Y-m-d');
    $fecha_ant = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fecha .' -1 day'));
    $fecha_sig = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fecha .' +1 day'));
?>


 <form id='marcador'>
        <button type='submit' name='fecha' value='<?$fecha_ant;?>'>Anteior</button>
        <input type='text' name='fecha'  value='<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>'>
        <button type='submit' name='fecha' value='<?$fecha_sig;?>'>Siguiente</button>
    </form>



    <div id='response'></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#marcador').submit(function(){
                $('#response').html("<b>cargando...</b>");
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'info.php',
                    data: $(this).serialize()
                })
                .done(function(data){ 
                    $('#response').html(data);
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    alert( "Error." );
                });

            return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

info.php

```
<?php



$fecha = strtotime($_POST['fecha']);

$anio = date('Y',$fecha);
$mes = date('m',$fecha);
$dia = date('d',$fecha);


echo $anio ."/". $mes ."/".  $dia;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tema de las fechas lo podés manejar así:

```
<?php
    $fecha = new DateTime("now");
    if(isset($_POST['fecha'])){
       $fecha = trim($_POST['fecha']);
       $fecha = filter_var($fecha, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
       $fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d",$_POST['fecha']); 
    }
    $str_fecha = $fecha->format("Y-m-d");
    $str_fecha_ant = $fecha->sub(new DateInterval("P1D"))->format("Y-m-d");
    $str_fecha_sig = $fecha->add(new DateInterval("P2D"))->format("Y-m-d");
?>
```

Por otro lado, si la llamada es por ajax, en lugar de devolver un form, sería más fácil devolver un json con las nuevas fechas, y actualizar el form que ya está en la página.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto, es para obtener la fecha anterior:

```
<php
$fecha = $_Post['fecha'];
$ayer = (strtotime($fecha)-3600);
$result = date("Y/m/d",$ayer);
?>
```

Fecha del día siguiente:

```
<?
$dia_manana = date('d',time()+84600);
$mes_manana = date('F',time()+84600);
$ano_manana = date('Y',time()+84600);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

En el `button`, en vez de un `type="submit"` as un `type="button"` y le colocas un `onclick="my_function();"`

```
<br>

function my_function(){<br>
    $.ajax({<br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;type: "POST",<br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;dataType: "JSON",<br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;url: 'info.php',<br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;data: $('#marcador').serialize()<br>
    }).done(function(data){ <br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;$('#response').html(data.fecha);<br>
    })<br>
    .fail(function() {<br>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;alert( "Error." );<br>
     });<br>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;return false;<br>
  });<br>
}<br>

Tu archivo info.php tiene que devolver un json algo como esto: <br>
$fecha = $anio ."/". $mes ."/".  $dia;<br>
echo json_encode(array('fecha'=>$fecha));
```

Comment: Me da error, me falto agregar esto en la pregunta, va dentro del index.php                    <?php
        $fecha = date('Y-m-d');
        $fecha_ant = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fecha .' -1 day'));
        $fecha_sig = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fecha .' +1 day'));
    ?>